# I have three table books and users and orders, so I want to select all books with info orders by used_id

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql

I have three table books and users and orders, so I want to select all books with info orders by used_id .................................

```
  // get all order for user_id 
  const conn = await Client.connect()
  // const sql = 'SELECT * FROM order_books'
  const sql = 'SELECT * FROM books INNER JOIN order_books ON users.id = order_books.user_id;'


  const result = await conn.query(sql)

  conn.release()

  return result.rows
```

books

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY  KEY,
    title VARCHAR(150),
    totalpages integer,
    price integer,
    author VARCHAR(255),
    type VARCHAR(100),
    summary text
);
```

user

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY  KEY,
    firstName VARCHAR(150),
    lastName VARCHAR(150),
    email VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    phone VARCHAR(150),
    password VARCHAR(255)
);
```

orders

```
CREATE TABLE order_books (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    quantity integer NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint REFERENCES users(id) NOT NULL,
    books_id bigint REFERENCES books(id) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: you need all column of those three table then use * and if you want some selected column then right down column name place of *.

Comment: Please select your answered useful for other references.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
const sql = 'SELECT * FROM books 
INNER JOIN order_books ON books.id = order_books.books_id 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = order_books.users
order by users.id asc;'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    b.*, -- i would select only required columns
    ob.*,
    u.*
from
    books b
    join order_books ob (ob.books_id = b.id)
    join users u on (u.id = ob.user_id)
order by u.id asc
```